# Error "Not enough space on Windows" when transferring data to USB flash drive

Tags: windows, data-transfer, bug

I am trying to back up about 250GB into 1T Flash Drive. I tried multiple flash drives and I constantly get the same error:
[image]

But I am **not** moving it to my Windows disk. And I am certain I have enough space on the drive.
I also tried changing the flash drive type to NTFS and exfat.
How can I solve this, and why does it occur?
I tried checking checking out multiple similar questions such as: [Why a "Not enough space on disk" error on 7zip even with sufficient space?](https://superuser.com/questions/697771/why-a-not-enough-space-on-disk-error-on-7zip-even-with-sufficient-space)
But that didn't help

Comment: are you copying a lot of small files? [exFAT uses very large cluster size by default](https://superuser.com/q/785129/241386) so the space required would be larger than the total source file size. You must reformat it to a smaller cluster size or use NTFS. I don't think you're correctly formatting it as NTFS

Comment: @phuclv Yes but why does it matter? If every file is multiplied in size, by 400% max if I remember correctly, then I'll have, worst case, 4 times the total size I am transferring (which is actually 90GB and not 250GB as I previously mentioned). And yes I am 100% certain I formatted the flash drive to NTFS. I used a number of tutorials and did so using cmd, and via right-click on the flash drive (then format & change to NTFS)

Comment: who said that it's 400% max? It depends on the cluster size and file size. For example if the partition uses 2MB cluster and the file all are 1-byte long then it'll increase 209715200% in size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the OS, Windows, is trying to open archives, such as ISO or ZIP files, to transfer contents item-by-item to the USB flash drive. If that is the case, do not open the archive and drag files *separately* to the other drive, but drag the whole archive, instead.

You might also try the much more robust [robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) utility built into Windows. *robocopy* can be faster and more reliable than drag-and-drop in *Explorer* or using the *copy* command.

BTW, before doing anything else, use [diskmgmt.msc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/disk-management/overview-of-disk-management) or a third-party tool, such as free [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/) to check that the USB flash drive is correctly partitioned for your use. Likely, it should have one partition of ~1 TB (manufacturers do tend to over-state the actual size, but even 300 GB would be sufficient). If the drive has been formatted with multiple partitions, remove *all* partitions, then create a single partition for all free space, and then format it exFAT, to allow ISO files greater than 4 GB to be copied.

Comment: Agree with the rest, but I wouldn't use ExFAT. It's far too flimsy to be reliable for a backup. Use something [at least approximating] journaled, which would be NTFS for Windows, preferably on GPT/GUID not MBR.

Comment: @Tetsujin, it depends: for flash, exFAT is perhaps less stressful for writing, but an external HDD, I'd use NTFS. See also https://superuser.com/questions/257646/why-should-i-use-exfat-over-ntfs-on-removable-media